# Methods of finding roots of Nonlinear Algebric Equations

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson, fixed-point-iteration

Recently, I've been surveying the methods of solving nonlinear equations (both: methods that solve one equation and methods that solve a set of equations)..
According to some references, I found that there are two main categories;
1- **Bracketing methods** which are 1-The bisection method, 2-the false position method, and 3- the incremental search.
2- **Open methods** which are 1-Newton Raphson method, 2-Fixed Point iteration, 3-Secant Method, 4-Brent Method, 5-Muller Method, 6-Bairstow Method, 7-Broyden Method.

The problem is that I found there are more other methods that I can't put in a category like 1-BFGS, 2-Shamanskii method, 3-Chord method etc.. 
I also found hybrid methods that mixes other methods..

My question is:
1-I just want to know all the methods that can solve nonlinear algebraic equations so is there a source that helps me and that covers all the methods? (An understandable source as I'm not a mathematician)
2-I also want to know how to put these methods in the suitable category and if it is enough to make only these two categories (Bracketing and open methods)?
Thank you..

Comment: Newton's method is a fixed-point method. Brent's and Muller's methods are bracketed methods. Bairstow is a variant of Newton's method to find quadratic factors of polynomials.

Comment: Most methods are going to be "open" in the sense that they are not bracketed. This is a bad thing in terms of reliability of solution but it is a good thing because a bracket is frequently difficult to furnish in the first place.

Comment: (Cont.) The biggest thing distinguishing such methods are: do they use analytical derivatives? Do they use approximate derivatives? Or do they not use derivatives at all? Or do they not use derivatives at all? Newton uses analytical derivatives; various Newton-like methods including BFGS use approximate derivatives (these are basically multidimensional versions of the secant method); some methods like bisection don't use derivatives at all.

Comment: see here i hope this will help you http://math.niu.edu/~dattab/MATH435.2013/ROOT_FINDING.pdf